# DataSources in WebSphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, datasource, jndi

There is a data source with JNDI name "jdbc/project/SimpleDS" defined in WebSphere 7. In admin console I changed the data source properties: db_name, db_port, db_host , login and password.

Whereby the deployed applications which references to "jdbc/project/SimpleDS" data source throws the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [jcc][t4][2013][11249]
[4.8.87] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid. ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000DSRA0010E: 
SQL State = 28000, Error Code = -4,214
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:674)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:120)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.p(b.java:2060)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:1649)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.r(db.java:799)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.k(db.java:353)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.c(db.java:133)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.Wc(b.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1184)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:5175)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.d(b.java:743)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:685)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:368)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:308)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.c.<init>(c.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2PooledConnection.<init>(DB2PooledConnection.java:192)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XAConnection.<init>(DB2XAConnection.java:56)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource.getXAConnection(DB2XADataSource.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1338)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1375)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalDB2UniversalDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalDB2UniversalDataStoreHelper.java:1855)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:2624)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1695)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2086)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1761)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2636)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:701)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:635)
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04

How can I replace the data source properties in runtime?

Comment: Maybe you are using authentication alias, and you forgot to update it to the correct user/password. The best way is to restart the server after changing datasource properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use JNDI to get the connection to DB.

You shouldn't be worried about what are the settings\credentials of datasource. That's the idea of JNDI.

If you need to change the settings of connection in dynamic, perhaps you'd better to restrain from JNDI and use custom connection creation mechanism.

If you are working on z/OS, then you can read "Propagating user credentials to DB2 using JDBC Type 2 driver" in [WebSphere Application Server V7.0 Security Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247660.html?Open&pdfbookmark)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop and start the node(s) in order to effect. You can do it by running following commands:

```
cd <was_home>/profiles/<node_name>/bin
```

**For Linux:**

To Stop the node

```
./stopNode.sh
```

To Start the Node

```
./startNode.sh
```

**For Windows**

To Stop the node

```
stopNode.bat
```

To Start the Node

```
startNode.bat
```

Additionally, verify that the username and password which you provided are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ripplestart is the only way to fake such a thing. This way users have minimal impact. Unless you have the A and B cluster model where Cluster B is already offline awaiting such a change before being brought online. There is no way that I know of to change the credentials during runtime without at least a rolling recycle of the App Servers.